# Переместить html-элемент из одного контейнера в другой при определенном разрешении

Tags: javascript, slider

Пытаюсь сделать адаптивным следующий элемент:

[image: скриншот макета]

Не хотелось делать длинную вертикальную портянку из восьми блоков, поэтому решил сделать слайдером использовав библиотеку [peppermint](http://wd.dizaina.net/scripts/peppermint/). Разбил на два слайда: по 4 элемента в каждом.

[вот демка](https://yurifedorov.github.io/code-example/example/peppermint-slider/peppermint-slider.html)

На смартфонах и планшетах все супер! А вот большими столкнулся с проблемой.
При ширине окна браузера более 1024px мне нужно отобразить все 8 элементов.

Решение придумал такое:
1) перенести 4 элемента из второго слайда в первый;
2) удалить второй слайд из DOM
3) все это должно происходить при разрешении > 1024px

но не знаю как реализовать, я в js пока не силен

HTML

```
<div class="peppermint" id="peppermint">

    <figure>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>Design quality</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Built to last</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
            <div> 
                <h3>Sign up & see why</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Get Started Now &rarr;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </figure>

    <figure>
        <div>
            <div> 
                <h3>Our clients</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Our clients &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div> 
                <h3>How to shoo great</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Find Out more &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div> 
                <h3>Perfect pictures</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Find Out more &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Start somthing new</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Get Started Now &rarr;</a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </figure>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.peppermint {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.peppermint__slide-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.peppermint__slide-container_full {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}


.peppermint__element {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}
```

JS

```
var slider = Peppermint(document.getElementById('peppermint'), {
    dots: true,
    slideshow: false,
    disableIfOneSlide: true,
    speed: 500,
    slideshowInterval: 5000,
    mouseDrag: true,
    stopSlideshowAfterInteraction: true,
    slidesContainer: undefined,
    onSetup: function(n) {
      console.log('Найдено слайдов: ' + n);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут  все для примера. смотри сам куда перемещать что. 100 поменяй на 1024

```js
    let slide1 = document.querySelector('#slideOne');
    let slide2 = document.querySelector('#slideTwo');
let childrens = Array.from(slide2.childNodes)
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)").matches) {
// перемещаем контент второго слайда в первый
      slide1.append.apply(slide1,childrens)
      slide2.remove()
    } else{
       slide2.append.apply(slide2,childrens)
       slide1.parentNode.insertBefore(slide2, slide1.nextSibling)
    }
```

```css
.peppermint {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }

.peppermint__slide-container {
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
float: left;
}

.peppermint__slide-container_full {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

/* общие слили для всех элементов слайдов (например padding) */
.peppermint__element {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
.peppermint__element > h3 {
padding: 0;
margin-top: 5%;
font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="peppermint" id="peppermint">

        <figure id="slideOne">
            <div class="peppermint__slide-container">
            <div class="peppermint__element" id="peppermint__slide-one">
                <h3>Design quality</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="peppermint__element" id="peppermint__slide-two">
                <h3>Built to last</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="peppermint__element peppermint__element_full" id="peppermint__slide-three"> 
                <h3>Sign up & see why</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Get Started Now &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </figure>

        <figure id="slideTwo">
            <div class="peppermint__slide-container">
            <div class="peppermint__element js-clone" id="peppermint__slide-four"> 
                <h3>Our clients</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Our clients &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="peppermint__element" id="peppermint__slide-five"> 
                <h3>How to shoo great</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Find Out more &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="peppermint__element" id="peppermint__slide-six"> 
                <h3>Perfect pictures</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Find Out more &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="peppermint__element" id="peppermint__slide-seven">
                <h3>Start somthing new</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                <a href="#">Get Started Now &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </figure>

    </div>
```

Comment: Сделал и поменял на 1024px, теперь все более менее хорошо. Вот [результат](https://yurifedorov.github.io/dist/components/sliders/slider.html). Но есть один нюанс, если окно браузера уменьшать до 1024px и ниже то предыдущее состояние не возвращается. Получается вот так ![скриншот](http://joxi.ru/BA0RVeGFMpd7Lm)  По идее при: if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)").matches) должен обратно вернуться второй слайд вместе с 4 элементами.

Comment: .. так смотри.. все перемещено уже..  теперь получается что тебе нужно переместить вес обратно  тоесть добавить к if  else  где перемечтить все блоки обратно

Comment: да, я понял что надо сделать ![так](http://joxi.ru/vAWbNa5i1d61v2). вроде все просто, но я в синтаксисе и методах js еще пока плохо понимаю. Если не трудно, подскажи как должна выглядеть строка,  которая вернет все на исходную?

Comment: я немного переделал  результат..но возможно придется добавить слушатель на ресайз.

Comment: Не помогло, ресайз не замечает пока не перезагрузить страницу. Но, спасибо за подсказку. Думаю слушатель поможет, буду пробовать...